# How to calculate a french curve in SVG?

Tags: javascript, math, svg, graphics, bezier

This seems simple, but I can't wrap my head around it. I have two points I need to connect using a french curve. I made an example in plain JavaScript using SVG, so a solution for that would be great, although I would also welcome some kind of formula-based approach that translates into other languages.

Example code is hosted here: https://jsfiddle.net/se6kf95u/

```
const nameSpace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

// Setup SVG Container
var svg = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'svg')
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '0 0 400 200')
document.body.appendChild(svg);

// Draw Example 1
const line1 = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'line');
line1.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1','50');
line1.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1','100');
line1.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2','100');
line1.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2','50');
line1.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'black');
svg.appendChild(line1);

// Draw Example 2
const line2 = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'line');
line2.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1','50');
line2.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1','150');
line2.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2','200');
line2.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2','120');
line2.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'black');
svg.appendChild(line2);
```

And here's a poor animation of what I want to achieve:

[image]

**Important**: the decision on how the curve *rises* (above the line, or below the line) would be made manually, this is not an automatic decision. In the example I use, A would go below the line, and B would go above the line, if that makes any sense. I don't have *any other input parameters* or information. The **coordinates of a starting point** and an **end point**, and if the curve goes **over or under the line**.

*Side note: I used a poorly up-scaled french-curve image I found online, not 100% certain the example below is pixel-correct, may be off quite a bit.*

Comment: *I don't have any other input parameters or information.* Wouldn't you also need to know the size of the French curve template you are trying to fit? Or can we assume the scale is fixed?

Comment: Interesting question, @samgak — not sure about their scale. The underlying idea of all of this originates from traditional fashion pattern making, where a french curve is simply a ruler you can buy. You slide it up to the two points, adjust the ruler until the two points are hit nicely by the curve, and trace along it. I know too little about the french curve rulers to know for certain what determines their size. Here's a reference ruler for it: https://www.greatart.co.uk/burmester-curve-ruler.html

Comment: (for instance, it sounds like what you're looking for is how to place "an SVG path" of which you don't know the mathematical formula such that it touches two points, and how to move the shape "through"/"along" one of those points while keeping the shape anchored to the other point, too. That description drastically changes the help you need, and probably at which point in that solution you're even stuck)

Comment: Wouldn't bezier curves be a more logical solution? You then could easily add constraints such as tangent continuity. Curve rulers only make sense when you don't have a computer. Bézier introduced his curves in the 1960s to get rid of the severe restrictions of curve rulers.

Comment: Reason for this entire thing is to generate a classic trouser (tailored pants) pattern based on input parameters. The classic trouser pattern is built by calculating a few X/Y points on a canvas, and then connect them. Some connections are straight lines, other connections are made (when a tailor does it) using a french curve ruler. I want to emulate the exact curve the tailor would draw using his ruler. You can see an example of it here: https://dpstudio-fashion.com/791-thickbox_default/classical-trouser-base-pattern-without-darts.jpg — does that add enough detail? Thanks!

Comment: It does not: if you use words like "the exact curve" then you're suggesting there is an exact curve, when the whole point of a French Curve is that it can connect two points in a near-infinitenumber of ways, with wildly different connecting curvatures. So ignore the "fashion" part: it is irrelevant for the _programming_ problem. You have two points, and a French Curve: what do you want to have happen? What are the restrictions (points-should-be-on-the-curve is one of the obvious ones, what else?), and what are acceptable results, and what _aren't_ acceptable results?